# Authorization Flow with PKCE : "Showing Login: user is not authenticated"

Tags: identityserver4, oidc-client-js

We have setup a vueJs spa running on node on its own domain.

We have setup an asp.net core IdentityServer4 application on another domain.

We are trying to use Authorization code PKCE flow.

We have looked at a few articles, but most have a different configuration, using either Implicit flow or a MVC client on the same domain.

Here's the config of the client:

```
import Oidc from 'oidc-client';

   var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager({
     authority: "https://localhost:44363",
     client_id: 'Code Autho',
     redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080',
     response_type:'code',
     scope: 'openid profile email api1',  
})

export default mgr;
```

Here is the client designed in IdentityServer config :

```
           new Client
            {
                ClientId = "Code Autho",
                ClientName = "Code With PKCE",
                RedirectUris = {
                    Uri.EscapeUriString("http://localhost:8080")
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"http://localhost:8080"},
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequirePkce = true,
                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    "api1"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse
            }
```

The logs :

```
2019-06-21 11:41:54.396 +02:00 [INF] Starting IdentityServer4 version 2.4.0.0
2019-06-21 11:41:54.407 +02:00 [INF] You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
2019-06-21 11:41:54.412 +02:00 [INF] Using the default authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer
2019-06-21 11:41:54.412 +02:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication
2019-06-21 11:41:54.412 +02:00 [DBG] Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in
2019-06-21 11:41:54.412 +02:00 [DBG] Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out
2019-06-21 11:41:54.412 +02:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge
2019-06-21 11:41:54.413 +02:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid
2019-06-21 11:41:54.757 +02:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: http://localhost:8080
2019-06-21 11:41:54.760 +02:00 [DBG] Client list checked and origin: http://localhost:8080 is allowed
2019-06-21 11:41:54.760 +02:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:8080
2019-06-21 11:41:54.776 +02:00 [DBG] Login Url: /Account/Login
2019-06-21 11:41:54.776 +02:00 [DBG] Login Return Url Parameter: ReturnUrl
2019-06-21 11:41:54.777 +02:00 [DBG] Logout Url: /Account/Logout
2019-06-21 11:41:54.777 +02:00 [DBG] ConsentUrl Url: /consent
2019-06-21 11:41:54.777 +02:00 [DBG] Consent Return Url Parameter: returnUrl
2019-06-21 11:41:54.777 +02:00 [DBG] Error Url: /home/error
2019-06-21 11:41:54.777 +02:00 [DBG] Error Id Parameter: errorId
2019-06-21 11:41:54.799 +02:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
2019-06-21 11:41:54.805 +02:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
2019-06-21 11:41:54.805 +02:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
2019-06-21 11:41:54.807 +02:00 [DBG] Start discovery request
2019-06-21 11:41:54.975 +02:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
2019-06-21 11:41:54.988 +02:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
2019-06-21 11:41:54.989 +02:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
2019-06-21 11:41:54.997 +02:00 [DBG] Start authorize request
2019-06-21 11:41:55.010 +02:00 [DBG] No user present in authorize request
2019-06-21 11:41:55.013 +02:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2019-06-21 11:41:55.033 +02:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Code Autho succeeded.
2019-06-21 11:41:55.044 +02:00 [DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
2019-06-21 11:41:55.078 +02:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2019-06-21 11:41:55.094 +02:00 [INF] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{"ClientId":"Code Autho","ClientName":"code autho Klanik Code With PKCE","RedirectUri":"http://localhost:8080","AllowedRedirectUris":["http://localhost:8080"],"SubjectId":"anonymous","ResponseType":"code","ResponseMode":"query","GrantType":"authorization_code","RequestedScopes":"openid profile email api1","State":"a53f2786c13d460fa5271652c9871234","UiLocales":null,"Nonce":null,"AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses":null,"DisplayMode":null,"PromptMode":null,"MaxAge":null,"LoginHint":null,"SessionId":null,"Raw":{"client_id":"Code Autho","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8080","response_type":"code","scope":"openid profile email api1","state":"a53f2786c13d460fa5271652c9871234","code_challenge":"ih1wDabwyipUIsHxQcdi6tCyhOy9pzYyLyWn3A6R_Kw","code_challenge_method":"S256"},"$type":"AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"}
2019-06-21 11:41:55.103 +02:00 [INF] Showing login: User is not authenticated
```

Expected : we are redirected to http://localhost:8080 AND the user is authenticated. (We do have a login component on localhost:8080 expecting a username/password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the main point: *Code With PKCE* is one of so called interactive flows where user agent is redirected to identity provider login screen for entering the credentials. So you still have to present your login screen at your Identityserver host.

Comment: So my login page, and the redirect Uri, should be on identityserver? That was unclear. Do you have a link explaining that?

Comment: only the first. `redirect_url` is where identity provider redirects one **after** login

Comment: Thank you. 

I will validate your answer.